# EncryptMessage returns SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN

Tags: winapi, sspi, schannel

When using the EncryptMessage (SChannel) from the win32 API with a valid context, I am supplying the four buffers in the correct order I get the SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN response which according to the documentation is No SECBUFFER_DATA type buffer was found. I know that the set of pvBuffers should be allocated from contiguous memory for speed but for simplicity I have made it obvious what is what. Can anyone see what the problem could be?

Thanks,
Bruce

The code is the following;

```
procedure TTCPSocket.SSPEncryptBuffer(SSPCtx: PCtxtHandle; InData: PAnsiChar; InDataLength: Cardinal);
var
  SecStatus: TSecurityStatus;

  SecBufDesc: TSecBufferDesc;
  SecBufs: packed array [0 .. 3] of TSecBuffer;
begin
  SecBufs[0].BufferType := SECBUFFER_STREAM_HEADER;
  SecBufs[0].cbBuffer := FSecPkgSizes.cbHeader;
  SecBufs[0].pvBuffer := AllocMem(FSecPkgSizes.cbHeader); 

  SecBufs[1].BufferType := SECBUFFER_DATA;
  SecBufs[1].cbBuffer := InDataLength; 
  SecBufs[1].pvBuffer := InData; 

  SecBufs[2].BufferType := SECBUFFER_STREAM_TRAILER;
  SecBufs[2].cbBuffer := FSecPkgSizes.cbTrailer;
  SecBufs[2].pvBuffer := AllocMem(FSecPkgSizes.cbTrailer);

  SecBufs[3].BufferType := SECBUFFER_EMPTY;
  SecBufs[3].cbBuffer := 0;
  SecBufs[3].pvBuffer := nil;

  SecBufDesc.ulVersion := SECBUFFER_VERSION;
  SecBufDesc.cBuffers := 4;
  SecBufDesc.pBuffers := @SecBufs[0];

  SecStatus := EncryptMessage(SSPCtx, 0, @SecBufDesc, 0);

  if SecStatus <> SEC_E_OK then
  begin
    // Error code..
  end;
end;
```

I used STRACE injected into the executable and this line looks interesting;

```
12/07/2009 23:10:30:635 - SecBuffer #0 BufferType:0x00000007 cbBuffer:5
12/07/2009 23:10:30:636 - SecBuffer #1 BufferType:0x00000001 cbBuffer:13
12/07/2009 23:10:30:636 - SECBUFFER_DATA - 13 byte(s) / EncryptMessage - INPUT 
=====================================================
      00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f   0123456789abcdef

0000: 68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 21 00            hello world!.
=====================================================
12/07/2009 23:10:30:636 - SecBuffer #2 BufferType:0x00000006 cbBuffer:36
12/07/2009 23:10:30:636 - SecBuffer #3 BufferType:0x00000000 cbBuffer:0
12/07/2009 23:10:30:636 - 

 *** WARNING : EncryptMessage failed (80090308) ***
```

Which looks as though the OS is getting the correct information.

I have searched a bit and found that 80090308 usually means something wrong with the certificate in that the full name of the server should be in the subject, CN=www.foobar.com but this didn't fix the problem either, the certificate and CA are generated with OpenSSL.

Comment: Glad to see you're macking progress

Comment: Can you confirm that `FSecPkgSizes.cbHeader` value is 5, `InDataLength` value is between 1 and 16362 and `FSecPkgSizes.cbTrailer` value is 16 ?

Comment: Yes, making progress :). Thanks again for your help before. In this case cbHeader is 5, InDataLength is 23 (It says it would complain if it is too small) but cbTrailer is 36 not 16, I hard coded it to 16 but still no joy.

Comment: I've added a comment to the question you refer to (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727259) about the "solution" by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat of a guess here since this seems like a common problem people run into when trying to do anything with asymmetric crypto on Windows.

If it is a self-signed CA and your cert is signed with the self signed CA, you need to import the CA into your computer's trusted CA store.

To do this, run MMC and do the following:

1. File->Add/Remove Snap In
2. Add the "Certificates" snap in and choose "Computer Account" if you want it to apply for all users on the computer.
3. Open the "Trusted Root Certificate Authorities->Certificates" tree node.
4. Right click on "Certificates" and choose import.
5. Import the CA certificate file.  (It should accept the PEM encoded version without a problem.)

While the CN will need to match the name of the machine in your machine certificate in most cases, the CA validation will fail if the CA is not imported into the Windows trust storage.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for thinking about it, however I can already get a valid certificate from the store and the handshake works. Are you suggesting that you could get SEC_E_OK for both sides of the handshake and still the EncryptMessage would fail because of the certificate not being "right"?

Comment: It is possible that the establishing of the context is just a 3 way TCP handshake and that it doesn't go through with the TLS/SSL handshake until the first message is sent.  You could watch the connection with something like Wireshark and see if more than just the TCP connection is established before you try to encrypt the message.  If SChannel is delaying the TLS/SSL handshake until the first message, then it is possible that it will indeed fail even after a context is successfully established.  Running Filemon or Regmon (sysinternals) might show you when it accesses the local CA store too.

Comment: I am handling the handshake in my own code, passing the "tokens" back and forth until SEC_E_OK and the last token has been transmitted, so I am pretty sure that the handshake has occurred. I have been using the System Event viewer to see that credentials have been established.

Answer (score 2):

When you set up your context on both client and server using;

```
InitializeSecurityContext // Schannel Client
AcceptSecurityContext // Schannel Server
```

pay very special care to the flags you pass in for the type of context you want as that determines the types of SecBuffer(s) that you need for both EncryptMessage and DecryptMessage. For instance I am currently using;

```
  FClientContextFlags :=
    ISC_REQ_CONFIDENTIALITY or
    ISC_REQ_STREAM or
    ISC_REQ_ALLOCATE_MEMORY;

  FServerContextFlags :=
    ASC_REQ_CONFIDENTIALITY or
    ASC_REQ_STREAM or
    ASC_REQ_ALLOCATE_MEMORY;
```

which means that for EncryptMessage you need four SecBuffers of;

```
SECBUFFER_STREAM_HEADER
SECBUFFER_DATA
SECBUFFER_STREAM_TRAILER
SECBUFFER_EMPTY
```

and for DecryptMessage you also need four SecBuffers of;

```
SECBUFFER_DATA
SECBUFFER_EMPTY
SECBUFFER_EMPTY
SECBUFFER_EMPTY
```

My problem was that I had *_REQ_STREAM and *_REQ_CONNECTION which on closer reading of the documentation are essentially incompatible. This is on top of making sure you have a valid certificate/trusted etc.

I hope this helps someone.

Bruce